# Porpoising and FIA simulations

Tags: formula-1

To arrive at 2022 regulations, it is said that FIA ran thousands of hours of simulations on what should be the design of the F1 car. But while they did so, was the porpoising effect brought out effectively in their simulations.

It seems that none of the CFD simulations carried out by F1 teams predicted porpoising. Is it true and whether the same thing happened with FIA simulations as well?

Comment: Recent controversy on this matter during Canadian GP in the form of a technical directive by F1 is a clear indication that FIA simulations did not predict vertical oscillations while they were finalizing the regulations for 2022 cars.

Now can we say that there were indeed shortcomings in CFD simulations by FIA that eventually opened the doors for Red Bull to take maximum advantage of the regulations?

It is quite evident from the helmet cam that porpoising is least in Red Bull cars.

Comment: I think that should be an answer, not a comment.