# Porpoising controversy at Canadian GP

Tags: formula-1

I had earlier posted a question in Sports Stack Exchange on porpoising ([Porpoising and FIA simulations](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/27852/porpoising-and-fia-simulations))

Recent controversy on this matter during Canadian GP in the form of a technical directive by F1 is a clear indication that FIA simulations did not predict vertical oscillations while they were finalizing the regulations for 2022 cars.

Now can we say that there were indeed shortcomings in CFD simulations by FIA that eventually opened the doors for Red Bull to take maximum advantage of the regulations?

It is quite evident from the helmet cam that porpoising is least in Red Bull cars.

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate as any possible answers will be the same as to your earlier question. Feel free to add this information to your earlier question if you think that improves it.

Comment: @Philip Kendall : My earlier question was not answered. However, I have included a comment in my earlier post. Thank you.

Comment: You can answer your question yourself, if you feel that the technical directive is proof that the FIA's simulations didn't show porpoising as being an issue.